# magento 2: error loading jquery files

Tags: magento2

I add 2 js files to my theme using requirejs, but I get these error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'captcha' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autocomplete' of undefined
```

These errors are on files that I don't add, are magento 2 js files